# Duplicate entry 'Manufacturer Name-0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm an intermediate at best and help will greatly be appreciated. I'm trying to upload csv file with database of drugs, manufacturer, generic names etc.

I use this for the .php

$this->db->insert('acc_coa',$manufacturer_coa);
}

```
    $check_category = $this->db->select('*')->from('product_category')->where('category_name',$insert_csv['category_id'])->get()->row();
    if(!empty($check_category)){
        $category_id = $check_category->category_id;
    }else{
            $categorydata=array(
        'category_name'         => $insert_csv['category_id'],
        'status'                => 1
        );
              if ($count > 0) {
    $this->db->insert('product_category',$categorydata);
}
```

And this for database:

CREATE TABLE `acc_coa` (
`HeadCode` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`HeadName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`PHeadName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`HeadLevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
`IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`IsTransaction` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`manufacturer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`IsGL` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`HeadType` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`IsBudget` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`IsDepreciation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`DepreciationRate` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
`CreateBy` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`CreateDate` datetime NOT NULL,
`UpdateBy` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`UpdateDate` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`HeadName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

But anytime i try i get this

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry 'Manufacturer Name-0' for key 'PRIMARY'

INSERT INTO `acc_coa` (`HeadCode`, `HeadName`, `PHeadName`, `HeadLevel`, `IsActive`, `IsTransaction`, `IsGL`, `HeadType`, `IsBudget`, `manufacturer_id`, `IsDepreciation`, `DepreciationRate`, `CreateBy`, `CreateDate`) VALUES ('502020000001', 'Manufacturer Name-0', 'Account Payable', '3', '1', '1', '0', 'L', '0', 0, '0', '0', '1', '2021-05-27 18:15:47')

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/efkwa/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: The row with `HeadName = 'Manufacturer Name-0'` already exists in the table. You cannot insert one more row with this value.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any rows already inserted? It looks like that the Primary-Key-Value "Manufacturer Name-0" is already present.
Maybe your insert is executed twice?

Try to execute

```
DELETE FROM acc_coa;
```

and then try to insert again.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you already entered an example / row with that value (Manufacturer Name-0), the primary key acts as a unique identifier for each example, therefore it cannot be repeated in other examples / rows of the table

Answer (score 0):

It's been resolved...

I deleted from line 691

```
            // Display errors
            return $this->display_error(array('Error Number: '.$error['code'], `enter code here`$error['message'], $sql));
```

But i would like to know why ?

Comment: normally, in the real programming world, deleting/opressing an error message doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Yeah i figured. I'm still trying to find out why though.

Comment: you could read on: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), which is the approach to go for

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in MySQL client:

Create and insert the data into a ***temporary*** or intermediate table:

```
CREATE TABLE acc_coa_tmp AS SELECT * FROM acc_coa WHERE 1 = 0;
```

**Note:** No primary key on new table `acc_coa_tmp`.

In PHP:

```
try {
   :
   $db->insert(...);
} catch (SqlException $ex) {
   // Failed insert CSV
   // SQL insert into new table acc_coa_tmp
   $db->insert(...);
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work on a live server.